# What data structure for reading / storing 500 objects

Tags: android, xml, data-structures

When my application starts I need to load about 500 objects from an xml page, like this:

```
<object>
<name>objectname</name>
<info>info</info>
<info2>info</info2>
<info3>info</info3>
<info4>info</info4>
<alias>false</alias>
</object>
```

Now I want to store this on the device, hoping the reading will be faster. Currently I use an `ObjectOutputStream` to write the objects.

```
private static void write(ArrayList<MyObject> objects, String fileName, Context context) {
        final File cacheDir = context.getCacheDir();
        final File objectsFile = new File(cacheDir.getAbsoluteFile() + File.separator + fileName);

        FileOutputStream fos = null;
        ObjectOutputStream oos = null;
        boolean keep = true;

        try {
            fos = new FileOutputStream(objectsFile);
            oos = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);

            oos.writeObject(objects);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            keep = false;
        } finally {
            try {
                if (oos != null)
                    oos.close();
                if (fos != null)
                    fos.close();
                if (keep == false)
                    objectsFile.delete();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
```

This is not a very fast solution, reading can take about 10-15 seconds. I'm showing the objects in a listview, so all objects need to be read in at once.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you considered using sqlite?

Comment: Yes, but I have little experience with that, so I don't know what to expect. Will it be faster, keeping in mind all objects are needed at once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best method to store such data would be in a database ([see here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db)).

Parse once and store the information in the database (one column for each attribute). It should be pretty fast to retrieve 500 records from the database :)

Comment: I agree, files are good for trivial applications, your talking about 500 objects at a minimum. While in this day in age 500 objects isn't THAT much to process, you will most likely see increased performance using a database.

Comment: I will try both this and @Ted 's suggestions, I'll let you know :)

Comment: This solution was significant fast than my and @Ted Hopp 's solutions. Teds solution saved about 300ms, this solution cuts the time in half! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you don't want to parse the XML each time you run the app. I'd suggest using a DataOutputStream and do your own encoding/decoding. It will be much faster than ObjectOutputStream. You can start the file by writing a count of the number of objects, as that will make reading everything back in a bit easier.

```
private static void write(ArrayList<MyObject> objects /* , other args */ ) {
    // ...
    try {
        dos = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(objectsFile));
        dos.writeInt(objects.size());
        for (MyObject object : objects) {
            dos.writeUTF(object.info);
            dos.writeUTF(object.info2);
            dos.writeUTF(object.info3);
            dos.writeUTF(object.info4);
            dos.writeBoolean(object.alias);
        }
        dos.flush();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        keep = false;
    } finally {
        try {
            if (dos != null)
                dos.close();
            if (keep == false)
                objectsFile.delete();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

For reading, just follow the same pattern with a DataInputStream:

```
ArrayList<MyObject> read( /* args */ ) {
    // ...
    ArrayList<MyObject> objects = new ArrayList<MyObject>();
    int n = dis.readInt();
    while (n-- > 0) {
        MyObject object = new MyObject();
        object.info = dis.readUTF();
        // etc.
        objects.add(object);
    }
    return objects;
}
```

Comment: You assumed right. The encoding/decoding of the objects, how would I do that? Would it just be a textbased file? For that matter, I could just save the xml file in the device storage?

Comment: I posted an outline of how I would code this. You could do it in a text file as well, but I like DataInputStream/DataOutputStream for this kind of stuff. You don't have to worry about file syntax, just match the order in which you read/write things.